# The rendered image is very different from the camera viewport. There seems to be some lighting issue and also the image does not render in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, lighting

The rendered image is vastly different from the image seen on the camera viewport.
[image: camera view]

[image: render]

Answer (score 1):

Check your *Outliner*, you have some objects that are hidden for preview but still visible for render:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Apparently the hidden plane was above and blocking the lights